# Will CoreData and NSUserDefaults have always loaded by the time the initial ViewController ViewDidLoad is called?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsuserdefaults

On app launch I try to auto-login the user if they already have credentials on the device. In my testing I sporadically observe the auto-login fail when it should have succeeded. Is it possible that the ViewDidLoad is being called before CoreData has fully initialised?

To check for auto-login I check:

1. That the user object exists, stored in CoreData. I store a reference to this user in NSUserDefaults that I use to fetch the CoreData object.
2. That the auth key exists, stored in Lockbox

   ```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
           super.viewDidLoad()

             if self.findUser() != nil && self.getAuthToken() != nil {
                 self.autoLogIn()
             }else{
                 self.showLogInScreen()
             }
   }

   func findUser() -> User? {

           let objectURL = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().URLForKey("userURI")
            if (objectURL == nil) {
                Debug().printString("objectURL == nil")
                return nil
            }


            let objectID = self.managedObjectContext?.persistentStoreCoordinator!.managedObjectIDForURIRepresentation(objectURL!)
            if objectID == nil {
                Debug().printString("objectID == nil")
                return nil
            }

            var currentUser: NSManagedObject?
            do {
                currentUser = try self.managedObjectContext?.existingObjectWithID(objectID!)
            } catch let error1 as NSError {
                currentUser = nil
                Debug().printString("error1.localizedDescription")
            }

           return currentUser as? User
   }

   func getAuthToken() -> String? {
       let authToken = Lockbox.stringForKey("authToken")
       return authToken
   }
   ```

Comment: The Core Data stack is lazily initialized that means at the moment of the first access

Comment: Hi,

you can call nsuserdefault or coredata at any where your access the app.because it saves data into the app database

Comment: Adding  `NSPersistentStore` to `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` can take unpredictable time, thus full initialisation of Core Data stack. If your first task rely upon Core Data than make a callback when Store is added and perform the task then.

Answer (score 1):

This issue turned out to be caused by an old version of Lockbox (1.4.x). Upgrading to v3 fixed the issue.

Thanks for all of the responses.

Answer (score 0):

Core Data is initialized whenever you initialize it. There's absolutely no magic to it, the initialization is done by your code. If you're using the code from Xcode's project templates, that happens in your app delegate class, and it happens automatically the first time you access the managed object context. If you're using your own code then obviously it happens whenever your code runs.

`NSUserDefaults` does not need to be initialized. If your code is running, user defaults is available. You don't need to do anything to get it ready, it's just there fore you.

Comment: I see, thanks. Yeah my CoreData is loaded in the AppDelegate on launch. I guess my issue must be something else, but at the moment I'm struggling to see where it could be.